# Merge [virtual-method] tag with [virtual-functions] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Recently the [virtual-method](/questions/tagged/virtual-method) (106) tag was created. It should be merged with [virtual-functions](/questions/tagged/virtual-functions) (385) tag. The [virtual-functions](/questions/tagged/virtual-functions) tag is more general and it is the older one, but should it be the one to live on? This seems disputable as I haven't heard of a virtual function which is not a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every virtual function is a method and every virtual method is a function. That's why they should be synonyms.

"Virtual function" seems to be the expression used more commonly (Google gives 670000 vs. 260000 hits), so probably it would be the appropriate main tag.